# Creating table of Outlook Inbox emails in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

**UPDATE:**

Current code below in accordance with recommended SQL construct: error in SqlString =

> Run-time error '3011': The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object ".  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.  If " is not a local object, check your network connection or contact the server administrator.

Of note, I am working on a USAF unclassified network system, and log in via CAC.

```
Sub InboxImport
    Dim SqlString As String
    Dim ConnectionString As String
    Dim EmailTableName As String
    Dim UserIdNum As String
    Dim EmailAddr As String
    Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olFol As Outlook.Folder`

    Set ol = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olNS = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olFol = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    EmailTableName = "MyInbox" 'My table name
    UserIdNum = Environ("USERNAME")  '1277523A... acct #
    EmailAddr = olFol.Parent.name 'user's email address
    ConnectionString = "Outlook 9.0;MAPILEVEL=" & EmailAddr & "|;PROFILE=Default Outlook Profile;TABLETYPE=0;TABLENAME=MyInbox;COLSETVERSION=12.0;DATABASE=C:\Users\" & UserIdNum & "\AppData\Local\Temp\"

    SqlString = "SELECT [From] As [Sender], [Sender Name] As SenderName, [Subject Prefix] & [Normalized Subject] As Subject, [Contents] As [Body], [Received] As [ReceivedTime]" & _
                " INTO [Email]" & _
                " From [" & ConnectionString & "].[MyInbox]"
    DoCmd.RunSQL SqlString
end sub
```

---

**Original text:**

I am attempting to pull default Outlook inbox emails into a table within Access.  I am able to use the wizard to successfully retrieve emails and populate the various columns and view my current inbox via Access table named "Inbox".

My Access database will be used by several employees at the same time, and I can't ask them to run the wizard for every different computer they log into.

I am using code copied from middle of the page...["Export Outlook Emails to Access table - VBA"](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/6b643ee8-c40d-4232-8477-d0c134e2169a/i-need-to-write-a-vba-that-will-export-outlook-emails-to-a-microsoft-access-database-table).

I'm attempting to use

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO [Email] " & _
     "([Sender], [SenderName], [Subject], [Body], [ReceivedTime])" & _
     "VALUES " & _
     "'" & objProp(i).Sender & "', '" & _     'ERROR!
     objProp(i).SenderName & "', " & _  'ERROR!
     objProp(i).Subject & "', '" & _
     objProp(i).Body & "', '" & _       'ERROR!
     objProp(i).ReceivedTime & "';"
```

The code stumbles looking at any `MailItem` property other than `.ReceivedTime` or `.Subject`, and those properties throw an error of...

> Run-time error '287': Application-defined or object-defined error

For my References - Database:

1. Visual Basic For Applications
2. Microsoft Access 15.0 Object Library
3. OLE Automation
4. Microsoft Office 15.0 Access database engine Object Library
5. Microsoft Internet Controls
6. Microsoft Outlook 15.0 Object Library

Comment: I'd suggest stepping through the code (with F8) and checking out the objProp(i) object with the Watch Window and/or Object Browser, to get some insight as to what's going on. Here's more info from Chip Pearson on **[Debugging VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)**.

Comment: Are you sure _MyInbox_ is the _foreign_ table name, so that's how the folder is called in Outlook, no  spaces? _Email_ is the table name in your database here.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth, is there a way to get the sender's email address?
(or any other contact properties of the sender? i.e. phone number, alias)

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend you don't take the tried approach when importing mail from Outlook. Access can natively work with Outlook Data Files in SQL queries. You can, of course, execute these queries using VBA. But it will be way more optimized.

The trick is getting the proper connection string. You can easily obtain the connection string by using the following process:

1. Create a linked table to the desired outlook folder under External Data -> More -> Outlook folder, choose linked table, select the folder
2. Use `Debug.Print CurrentDb.TableDefs!MyLinkedOutlookFolder.Connect` to obtain the connection string, and `Debug.Print CurrentDb.TableDefs!MyLinkedOutlookFolder.SourceTableName` to obtain the external table name
3. Execute the following query, using your obtained variables:

   ```sql
   SELECT [From] As [Sender], [Sender Name] As SenderName, [Subject Prefix] & [Normalized Subject] As Subject, [Contents] As [Body], [Received] As [ReceivedTime]
   INTO [Email]
   FROM [ThatConnectionString].[ThatSourceTableName]
   ```

Sample connection string:

```
Outlook 9.0;MAPILEVEL=me@example.com|;PROFILE=Default Outlook Profile;TABLETYPE=0;TABLENAME=Inbox;COLSETVERSION=12.0;DATABASE=C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\
```

Sample source table name:

```
Inbox
```

That's all you need, no complex VBA needed.

Comment: Do I need to select specific references within VB?  I get errors pointing to the connection string being too long/invalid characters: 
'Run-time error '3125': '9.0' is not a valid name. Make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long'

Comment: Most code shared is SQL. Only those Debug.Print statements should be executed in VBA. Can you share exactly what you're doing to get that error?

Comment: `SqlString = "SELECT [From] As [Sender], [Sender Name] As SenderName, 
                      [Subject Prefix] & [Normalized Subject] As Subject,
                      [Contents] As [Body], [Received] As [ReceivedTime]" & _
                    " INTO [Email]" & _
                    "From " & ConnectionString & ".MyInbox"

    DoCmd.RunSQL SqlString`

It seems to get to the connection string, and error is found at the '9.0' part of the string

Comment: Those brackets are required. Add them before and after the string.

Comment: ok - that got me somewhere, but I'm having a hard time connecting and get a _run-time error '3011': the Microsoft access database engine could not find the object ".  Make sure..._


The connection string = `[Outlook 9.0;MAPILEVEL=first.last@us.af.mil|;PROFILE=Outlook;TABLETYPE=0;TABLENAME=Inbox;COLSETVERSION=12.0;DATABASE=C:\Users\127753~1\AppData\Local\Temp\`                 
I appreciate all the help up to this point!

Comment: I'll need the full code. If you're using this with the same code as in the previous comment, you're missing a closing bracket. Will look at it tomorrow.