# Finding Outlook Email Address of mailitem via SQL/VBA with Access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, outlook

Using Access/VBA/SQL to get various email properties from the inbox as I transfer it into a new table "MyInbox".

```
Sub InboxImport()
    Dim SqlString As String
    Dim ConnectionString As String
    Dim EmailTableName As String
    Dim UserIdNum As String
    Dim EmailAddr As String
    Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olFol As Outlook.Folder

    Set ol = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olNS = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olFol = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    EmailTableName = "MyInbox"
    UserIdNum = Environ("USERNAME")  '1277523A...
    EmailAddr = olFol.Parent.Name 'Gives your user email address
    ConnectionString = "Outlook 9.0;MAPILEVEL=" & EmailAddr & "|;PROFILE=Default Outlook Profile;TABLETYPE=0;TABLENAME=MyInbox;COLSETVERSION=12.0;DATABASE=C:\Users\" & UserIdNum & "\AppData\Local\Temp\"

    SqlString = "SELECT [From] As [Sender], [Email] As [Email Addy], [Subject Prefix] & [Normalized Subject] As Subject, [Contents] As [Body], [Received] As [ReceivedTime]" & _
            " INTO [MyInbox]" & _
             " From [" & ConnectionString & "].[Inbox]"

    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.RunSQL SqlString
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Sub
```

I'm trying to find the "Sender Email" address for every email item in the inbox.  As run, it currently pops up with a "Enter Parameter..." with a blank value for [Email].

Is there a good compiled reference for looking up all these different kinds of email SQL terms?

Comment: What is the issue - error message, wrong result, nothing happens?

Comment: Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34922075/get-senders-email-address-with-excel-vba

Comment: I'm looking for what would replace [Email] in this SQL string.  "Sender", "Email Addy", "Subject", "Body", and "ReceivedTime" are my table column names.  
When I use [Sender Email Address] and run the sub, it gives me a pop-up, 'Enter Parameter... (for Sender Email Address).  If I type anything in there, it'll be the value that gets used for ever single table row in that column "Email Addy".

Comment: Why do you want to create a new table instead of inserting to existing table? I use SenderEmailAddress in different code to pull the email address from each mail item in folder. Unfortunately it is not working with your code.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the folder does not have this property by any name. It is a property of the mail item. Only solution I can see is looping through the mail items and executing SQL for each item. Cannot get SQL referencing folder as a whole to capture that property.

Comment: I ran some code that printed field names of a recordset of the Inbox attributes - there are 20. None of them correspond to the email address. However, I ran code to print the data from each record for the From and Sender Name fields. Sometimes the email address was returned for Sender Name and sometimes for both fields.

Comment: I should add that for the remainder of the records, neither field shows the email address.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was worried about.  I've been unable to pull sender/body values via the other VBA method [See my previous question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51665530/creating-table-of-outlook-inbox-emails-in-access) while trying to create an inbox table in access.   Any way to merge the two solutions?  PM me...

Comment: Both SQL actions work for me, just neither can reliably pull email address.

Answer (score 1):

Loop through email items. Unfortunately, the INSERT sql has issue with embedded special characters in the email body, apparently related to hyperlinks. I didn't think it worthwhile figuring out how to get around it.

```
Public Sub ImportEmails()

' Set up Outlook objects.
Dim ol As New Outlook.Application
Dim of As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim objItems As Outlook.Items
Dim mo As Outlook.MailItem, Atmt As Outlook.Attachment
'Set of = ol.GetNamespace("Mapi").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Repairs")
Set of = ol.GetNamespace("Mapi").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set objItems = of.Items

Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("MyInbox")

For Each mo In objItems

    'CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO MyInbox SELECT '" & mo.SenderEmailAddress & "' AS Sender, '" & _
        mo.SenderName & "' AS SenderName, '" & mo.Subject & "' AS Subject, '" & _
        mo.body & "' AS Body, #" & mo.ReceivedTime & "# AS Received"

    rst.AddNew
    rst!EmailAdd = mo.SenderEmailAddress
    rst!SenderName = mo.Sender
    rst!Subject = mo.Subject
    rst!body = mo.body
    rst!Received = mo.ReceivedTime
    rst.Update
    'For Each Atmt In mo.Attachments
    '    Atmt.SaveAsFile "C:\path\" & Atmt.FileName
    'Next

Next
End Sub
```

Comment: With this, I get _Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)': Method 'SenderEmailAddress' of object'_MailItem' failed_ (for SenderEmailAddress), _Application-defined or object-defined error_ (for Sender and Body)

I think I'm getting stone-walled by my Outlook security settings being on a government computer.

Comment: Could be because code works flawlessly on my personal laptop.

Comment: and this was the same findings from my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51665530/creating-table-of-outlook-inbox-emails-in-access).  I think I'm outta luck...